# Firebase - Mass Delete Through Online GUI

Tags: firebase

Let's say I have the following structure in my Firebase:

```
-myRootObject
    -1
    -2
    -3
    -4
    -5
```

I want to delete all keys greater than 2.  I'd like to do this without writing a script.  Is there a way to do this in the GUI - either through check boxes or by typing in a SQL-ish statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not using Firebases's Dashboard.  (At least that I'm aware of.)  There may be some 3rd party tools available.